# Banco de Dados com Back-End embutido

Tags: banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, back-end

Existe algum tipo de banco de dados que possa tratar e armazenar os dados como se fosse 2 em 1?
BackEnd e Bando de dados ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que deseja mas, me parece, que é algo do tipo "embedded". Neste caso avalie o SQLite https://sqlite.org/index.html

Comment: É conveniente que seus dados estejam bem organizados. Certamente um "bando" de dados não terá muita utilidade.

Comment: Não sei se era o que queria, mas sua dúvida não está clara. Em geral o backend (serviços, lógica de negócio, Integrações) é separado do SGBD, que pode ser "standalone" (rodar num servidor separado) ou "embedded" (embutido), como está na pergunta que linkei. Podem existir stored procedures e triggers no banco para tratar dados mas via de regra é mais recomendado para manutenção que se prefira fazer separado.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas você pode se conecta com o banco de dados pela sua própria aplicação

exemplo de um código em Java script (node js) usando o mysql:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')// Aqui é uma dependência instalada e esta sendo chamada

const con = mysql.createConnection
({
    host: '', // O host do banco. Ex: localhost
    user: '', // Um usuário do banco. Ex: user 
    password: '', // A senha do usuário. Ex: user123
    database: '' // A base de dados a qual a aplicação irá se conectar
});

con.connect((err) => {
    
   if (err) {
        console.log('Erro connecting to database...', err)
        return
    }
   else {
   console.log('Connection established!')
   }
})
```

Aqui você já se conectou com o banco de dados, é só prosseguir com a sua aplicação